# Pyinstaller faild to execute script when opened over windows open with

Tags: python, pyinstaller

With my Application it should be possible to open Files with my Programm. But when I click on myfile..mft > Open with > myexe_to_open_mft.exe Then the exe gets an error: Fatal error, faild to execute script. If I open the program regular without open with, I get no errors and if I open it via command prompt I get also no errors.
Thanks for the help!

(Edit: At the end I fixed this error by hided the console via ctypes)

```
pyinstaller --windowed -i icon.ico PickleViewer.py
```

[Image from the Script if run over command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZNjS.png)

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Output from pyinstaller

```
162 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
162 INFO: Python: 3.7.4
163 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
173 INFO: wrote 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\PickleViewer.spec
177 INFO: UPX is not available.
179 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Python\\Documents\\pickle_viewer',
'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Python\\Documents\\pickle_viewer']
180 INFO: checking Analysis
199 INFO: Building because 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\PickleViewer.py 
changed
200 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
206 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
211 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5148 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5191 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent 
assemblies of final executable
required by c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
32\python.exe
8448 INFO: Caching module hooks...
8463 INFO: Analyzing 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\PickleViewer.py
8789 INFO: Loading module hooks...
8789 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
8936 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
8938 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
9298 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
9871 INFO: checking Tree
9931 INFO: checking Tree
9984 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
9985 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
9989 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
9996 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
17315 INFO: Looking for eggs
17316 INFO: Using Python library 
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
17316 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
17331 INFO: Warnings written to 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\build\PickleViewer\
warn 
-PickleViewer.txt
17397 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\build\PickleViewer\xre 
f-PickleViewer.html
17499 INFO: checking PYZ
17501 INFO: Building because toc changed
17502 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\build\PickleViewer\PYZ 
-00.pyz
18467 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\build\PickleViewer\
PYZ- 
00.pyz completed successfully.
18499 INFO: checking PKG
18501 INFO: Building because 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\build\PickleViewer\PYZ 
-00.pyz changed
18502 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
18549 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
18554 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
32\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\runw.exe
18554 INFO: checking EXE
18556 INFO: Building because console changed
18556 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
18651 INFO: Copying icons from ['icon.ico']
18754 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 20 bytes
18755 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 22767 bytes
19067 INFO: Appending archive to EXE 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\build\PickleViewer\
Pick 
leViewer.exe
19249 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
19266 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory 
"C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\dist\PickleViewer" 
and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)y
21243 INFO: Removing dir 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\Documents\pickle_viewer\dist\PickleViewer
21736 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
33512 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found it:

`if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # we are running in a bundle
    frozen = 'ever so'
    bundle_dir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    # we are running in a normal Python environment
    bundle_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Edit:
didnt helped

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**

I made it by hiding the console via ctypes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this error, "Fatal error, failed to execute script"

This error because you compile a python script (.pyw not .py) to .exe format, BUT there's no GUI available in that script. So you must use the 'py' extension (in Pyinstaller, do not type '-W') or use PyGame, PyQT etc.

And Tkinter is not compatible with .pyw extension, so you should use 
PyGame or PyQt or other big library for GUI

Comment: So I'm using Tinker and a .py extension, if I understood you correctly these are the cretins. And I have no error if I start the script via command line... Whats wrong?

Comment: can you please screenshot so i can know what is your problem?

Comment: I can send te command for the build and a screenshot of the error, and a screenshot when i start if over command line

Comment: do not use --windowed, because it will make an error

Comment: or if you want to hide a console you can use ctypes

Comment: Added the infos to the Question at the top!

Comment: I done the same with console, but it didnt started.

Comment: If i start the script as python script i get no errors... And when I start it over the command line with parameters is starts also

Comment: did you enable sys.argv?

Comment: I think i found it

Comment: Now the error only comes up when I compile with noconsole/windowed mode!